# How can I get a PSQL array to JSON using IDIORM?

Tags: php, json, postgresql, idiorm

I've looked at [PSQL JSON Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE) for a while, but I'm still a little confused about how to get it working.  I have a text array in a particular row and want to pull it out into PHP and then insert into a JS var.

When I head to terminal and psql I put my query in it works great

```
SELECT array_to_json(COL) from TABLE where name ='foo';
```

However, when I create the same in a raw_execute in idiorm, I end up with a true boolean.  How do I get actual results from the raw_execute into a php var?  Where can I read more if this is an obnoxiously ignorant question?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out raw_execute returns a bool for success or failure...

After combing idiorm docs long enough found raw_query feature [here](http://idiorm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/querying.html#raw-queries).  I ended up putting my select statement from above into php var $sql and doing the following:

```
$result = \ORM::for_table('TABLE')->raw_query($sql)->find_one();
```

Because this was all being done inside a php foreach,

```
foreach(ORM::for_table("TABLE")->find_result_set() as $record) {
```

I was able to then insert the var into my JS dictionary

```
<script>
<?=record->name?> = {
    ...
    version: <?=isset($result->array_to_json) ? $result->array_to_json : '[]'?>
```

and it was then available in browser to display as desired.